# Select2, Chosen server side pre rendering is it possible

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-chosen

Is there any way to prepare html for Select2 or Chosen
and render all html on the server side to avoid shaking on the page
In my rails project I want create good UI but pre rendering seems not supported
Does anybody know some good solution to prerender select boxes?